# Phonegap iOS App Crashing on iPhone 6 when loading contact photos

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a phonegap application that crashes on iPhone6 with iOS 8 (It works fine on iPhone6+) when calling phonegaps contacts.find method.  This only happens with the 'photos' filter.  When it gets to this part of the code, the app immediately crashes. I remove the photos filter, and everything works fine.

Here is the code that I am using:

navigator.contacts.find(['name', 'phoneNumbers', 'photos'], function (contacts){ }, function (error) {   }, options);

I am using the latest version of phonegap.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.